# Large XML generation and reporting using Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, dom, sax

We have a requirement to export a lot of data present in DB to an XML (around 30 MB). It is kind of an import export feature that we need to implement. In addition to export, some of the data may need to be presented to the user as a pdf/html(online). 
The challenge that we is the size of the data(~30MB) the system has to handle both while creating an XML and also during trasformation.

Do you folks see an good solution for this problem? We have SQL Server 2008 and can use it to store the xml if needed.

Comment: I have transformed even larger XML documents with Saxon. Today, transforming *a few hundreds of megabytes* isn't a problem. For XML documents larger than this, some XSLT processors offer streaming capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I think [jasper report](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) will be useful for your scenario.

Comment: Performance wise, any idea on how it will effect when working on large XMLs? Do you know if it uses SAX or DOM or StAX?

Comment: I think jasper uses SAX parser. It should be able to handle large size XML file as it uses SAX parser. As far as performance is concerned, its always better to use existing well established tool rather than writing your own. This reporting tool is used by many company for professional purpose.